# Get click the actual click location in canvas after a css resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

First of all, let's suppose that I have the following canvas: `<canvas id="can" width="400" height="200" />`. And Then, I need to resize it with `width: 100%; height: auto;` to fit my responsive container. And now, let's suppose that my canvas got a width of 800. And the problem is that everytime when I try the get the position(x, y) of a click event, I get the coordinates relative to the actual mouse position.

To be clear, If I click the bottom-edge of the canvas, Insted of getting the position(400, 200), I get (800, 400).

Already searched on the web for a solution but I can't find my specific problem and neither jQuery or vanilla javascript seems to have a easy approach to the problem. The only solution that I thought of was using a kind of a mathematical relation between the actual canvas dimensions setted in the DOM and the width and height of it after the scaling, but I really can't figure how.

Comment: **The only recommended** way of resizing a canvas element is by setting its `width` and `height` properties **Don't use CSS for that !**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting wrong canvas height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198079/getting-wrong-canvas-height)

Comment: It's a live drawing application. I need all the users to see the whole drawing no matter of his screen size.

Comment: then decide of a canvas width and stick with it for all screen res

Comment: Ps: you can insert your canvas in a div with `oveflow:auto` so that your users with smaller screen size can scroll into it.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` property on your canvas element to transform the mouse coordinates to your canvas. It would work something like this:

```
function(clickEvent) {
   var canvas = document.getElementById("can")
   var transformedClickX = clickEvent.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
   var transformedClickY = clickEvent.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

   ...
}
```

Comment: That's the behaviour that I got: https://i.gyazo.com/d2b269ca4f853398bfb4b7456e106a07.gif

Comment: This now becomes a scaling issue. It's a little more complicated but you can refer to this question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625208/working-with-canvas-in-different-screen-sizes/8626456#8626456

Answer (score 0):

I think [this answer by @patriques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053642/4756173) is really helpful:

```js
function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y)
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    getCursorPosition(canvas, e)
})
```